# Find first non-blank row above selected cell

Tags: vba

I would like to select the first non-blank row above the selected cell (minus offset). For example, if a find `Machine 1` in the sheet `Grupos Produção` I want to return the `******* Grupo 1 *******` string.

```
********** Grupo  1  ********** 
    Machine 1
    Machine 2
```

I have the following so far, but it's not returning what I need.

```
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    FindString = Lcell.Value
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Grupos Produção").Range("A:Z")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
                upperRow = .Cells(Rng.Row, Rng.Column - 1).End(xlDown).Row
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get what I need based on @Sam 's answer

```
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                    Do While Rng.Row > 1 And Rng.Offset(-1, 0).Value <> ""
                        Set Rng = Rng.Offset(-1, 0)
                    Loop
                    grupo = Rng.Offset(-1, -1).Value
                    Lcell.Value = grupo
                End If
```

Comment: Could you tick @Sams answer as the accepted answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, I would do that with pleasure, but @Sam's answer does not solve the topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your code, but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
...
...
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    Do While Rng.Row > 1 And Rng.Offset(-1, 0).Value <> ""
        Set Rng = Rng.Offset(-1, 0)
    Loop
...
```

Once the cell is found, it works its way up until it finds an empty cell and stops just before.

Answer (score 0):

This will find the first non-blank cell (which will indicate the row is not blank) above the selected cell.

You need to check for:

- If the rest of the sheet is empty it will return the same address as your selection.
- If all cells above the selection are empty it will start from the bottom of the sheet until it reaches your selection again.

As you said the first non-blank cell it's using the `*` wildcard to search, and to make it look up from the selection it uses `xlPrevious`.

Still need to check if `rng` is nothing in case the entire sheet is empty.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim Rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:Z")
        Set Rng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=Selection, _
                              LookIn:=xlValues, _
                              LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            If Rng.Address = Selection.Address Or Rng.Row > Selection.Row Then
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            Else
                Rng.Select
            End If
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```